# Using FTP to move files in VB6

Tags: excel, ftp, vb6, file-transfer, legacy

I've recently been working with some legacy software using VB6 + Microsoft SQL.

In a nutshell, the software enables the processing of data found in excel sheets, these excel sheets, once processed are then moved into local folder found on a server at the company.

I would like to move everything to the cloud, and I am thinking of using FTP to facilitate the moving of files from the users local machine to the cloud server[AWS].

I'll be looking to move 100 excel files daily with the transfer of files happening straight after the file has been processed, therefore resulting in files being transferred randomly throughout the day.

My question is, as I am a recent graduate with only three months experience using VB6, is FTP the most suitable method to move files to a storage system on the cloud?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

FYI - The company has purchased an AWS Windows Server.

Comment: Yes, FTP (or rather the secure FTP over TLS/SSL) is the probably the most straightforward solution to transfer files to Windows server over an Internet.

Comment: One problem with FTP is that as a really old protocol Microsoft never provided much useful support for it in the OS.  About all you have are the IE libraries (UrlMon and friends).  There isn't any support at all for SFTP or FTPS.  WebDAV is usually a far better answer if you have the option, since it is fairly easy to build on top of the HTTP/HTTPS components provided in Windows.  There are plenty of VB6 code samples out there for this.  WebDAV is also far more firewall-friendly than any form of FTP.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, really appreciate it I'll start looking FTPS and other tech.

Thanks again!

Comment: My company has found Chilkat FTP to be solid and reliable over about 10 years. It is a low-cost addon and the ActiveX product works fine with VB6. See https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/ftp.asp for examples. There is a Zip component too, and more.

Comment: Ah, that's great. Thank you very much!